# XML as string content to Post API

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to POST a XML document to a API URL. The problems is C# special encoding keep creeping into the XML file.  the whole XML file.

```
        var content = new StringContent("<XML>", Encoding.UTF8, "text /xml");
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost/URL", content).Result;
```

So the  that has the password/headerinfo/data how do I get that into a string so C# can read it?

Or should I be doing something different to send an XML file with info to the URL? I am not the API genius either.

Answer (score 0):

I just wound up using a filestream to convert the file to bye array

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlFilepath))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());


            if (timeout < 0)
            {
                request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;
                request.Timeout = timeout;
            }

            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

                requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    return response.ToString();
                }
```